# C# multiple patterns in regex.replace()

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can i pass multiple patterns to the regex.replace() pattern parameter?

In PHP you just give up the array containing them. Is there some kind of same option in C#?

I'm looping through some usernames and some of those usernames are surrounded by html tags. The html tags are not all the same. But i do know which ones they are.

So if i can pass multiple patterns to look for in the regex.replace() pattern parameter, would be nice. Or i'll have to make for each html tag a separate pattern and run the regex.replace() function.

Hope i'm clear about what i'm trying to accomplish!

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
@Alan Moore,

Bottom line, removing all html tags out of a string, is what i'm trying to do.

[/EDIT]

Comment: You'll get better help if you tell us *what you're trying to do*, not *how you're trying to do it*.  Forget about that gimmick you know from some other language and just tell us what result you're trying to attain.  And please edit your question and put the information there, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a list of strings, each consisting entirely of a user name optionally enclosed in HTML tags?  It shouldn't matter which tags they are; just remove anything that *looks* like a tag:

```
name = Regex.Replace(name, @"</?\w+[^<>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
// I’m assuming you have a regex for each thing you want to replace
List<string> multiplePatterns = [...];

string result = Regex.Replace(input, string.Join("|", multiplePatterns), "");
```

Comment: This is a nice example.  I was looking for this to implement a generic way of adding one or more conditions to a Regex where I want to the user to be able to specify their own condition(s).  I'm assuming you could just as well provide a string array instead of a list.

Answer (score 5):

Use the regexp divider `|`, e.g.:

```
</?html>|</?head>|</?div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important and there's no risk of '<' or '>' in user names, this could work:

```
string RemoveTags(string s)
        {
            int startIndex = s.IndexOf('<');
            int endIndex = s.IndexOf('>');
            return startIndex >= 0 && endIndex >= 0 ? RemoveTags(s.Remove(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1)) : s;
        }
```